# validate two forms on submit

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have two forms, first form contains the textbox and second form contains a button. I want to validate the textbox using the button (jquery or javascript) :

```
<form name="contactus" method="post">
<input name="txtFirstname" id="Firstname" type="text" class="field" Value="First name*" style="width:300px" />
</form>

<form name="frm1" action="sendemail.php" method="post">     
<input id="send" type="image" src="images/sub.png" alt="Submit" style="float:right" />
</form>
```

how would i be able to do this when my textbox is not on 'frm1'

Comment: Oh God! Why would you want to do that ?

Comment: how do you think i should do it. I am completely new to php ... the reason i am doing it this way is because I will have multiple forms that will get changed on radiobutton click...and sends email

Comment: Forms are HTML, but the logical way is to use a single form in this case. Also every `form` tag is required to have an `action` attribute, according to the HTML specs.

Comment: but my scenario is different...i have few boxes at top of page, then few radio buttons that (using jquery) will show different forms with submit button... this way i take the top boxes and whatever they select and send email...hope it is clear

Comment: @Sam1 You should still only need one form for that. You may want to change its content depending on the radio button, but you still only need one form. Keep in mind that a form is not only able to, it is *supposed* to contain other block level elements such as `<div>`s and `<table>`s which hold the `<input>`s. You can simply update the contents of these elements based on the value of your radio buttons.

Comment: @DaveRandom , if i have one form what should the 'action' be when posting to different php files to send email(as i have multiple button)...

Comment: @Sam1 You could dynamically alter the `action` of the form with Javascript depending on which button was clicked. But I do also wonder whether you might be able to wrap all the submit handling code into a single script, and use the name/value of the submit input clicked to determine what to do. How different are the actions that are performed? Are you always submitting to scripts hosted on your own site?

Comment: @DaveRandom can you please show me an example of this....all i am doing depending on the radio button show different box and submit button and send email (including the textbox values).. and script will always be on my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are examples of the two approaches I suggested in the comments above:

**1) Using Javascript to alter the action attribute of the form depending on the button that was clicked:**

```
<form id='the_form' action='' method='post'>
  <input type='text' name='text_input' />
  <input type='button' id='button_1' value='Button 1' />
  <input type='button' id='button_2' value='Button 2' />
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var theForm = document.getElementById('the_form');
  $('#button_1').click(function() {
    theForm.action = 'script1.php';
    theForm.submit();
  });
  $('#button_2').click(function() {
    theForm.action = 'script2.php';
    theForm.submit();
  });
</script>
```

**2) Holding all the submit handler code in a single script (recommended):**

HTML:

```
<form id='the_form' action='script.php' method='post'>
  <input type='text' name='text_input' />
  <input type='submit' name='submit_1' value='Submit' />
  <input type='submit' name='submit_2' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST['submit_1'])) {
    echo 'You clicked button 1';
  } else if (isset($_POST['submit_2'])) {
    echo 'You clicked button 2';
  }
```

Comment: thanks for this, if I use method 2 and want the value to be 'Submit' for both buttons is that possible...

Comment: Yes, you just use the `name` to determine which button was clicked instead of the `value`. See edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
$('#send').click(function(){
    var textVal = $('#Firstname').val();
    //your validation code goes here
});
```

Comment: this would work but what should i do to prevent the page from reloading if textbox is empty

Comment: if(textVal == '') return false;